# Postcondition the definition was not found error at the time of creating Automation plan by code

Tags: xconnect, marketing-automation

My code for creating Automation Plan

```
var manager = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetDefinitionManagerFactory().GetDefinitionManager<IAutomationPlanDefinition>();

var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Guid planId = Guid.NewGuid();

Guid entryActivityGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

AutomationPlanDefinition plan = new AutomationPlanDefinition(planId, "later"+ planId, culture, "later plan", DateTime.UtcNow, "sitecore\\admin")
{
    ReentryMode = AutomationPlanReentryMode.Single,
    Description = "Later",
    EndDate = currentTime.AddDays(3),
    EntryActivityId = entryActivityGuid
};

Guid activityTypeGuid = Guid.Parse("51774DB5-B90B-4189-9613-104039723A0B");

var emailActivity = new AutomationActivityDefinition
{
    Id = entryActivityGuid, // ID of this instance
    ActivityTypeId = activityTypeGuid,
    Paths =
      {
        {  "MessageId", Guid.Parse("E0D23B31-30E9-4F3F-AA98-826FD8F4A3A5")},
      }
};

plan.AddActivity(emailActivity);

manager.SaveAsync(plan, true);

return plan.Id.ToString();
```

At this line **manager.SaveAsync(plan, true);**

I am getting this error:

> $exception {"Postcondition 'the definition was not found: 14108e3c-8548-4339-baed-aa75add6be23 should be greater than 0' failed. The actual value is 0."} Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.PostconditionException"**

and **14108e3c-8548-4339-baed-aa75add6be23** is the id of automation plan.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore 9 do you use? Initial version or Update 1?

Comment: It is sitecore Update 1

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your scenario with exactly same code also on `Sitecore 9 Update 1`.

On my side everything went through without any problem as you can see on below images.

[image]

[image]

I think you haven't deployed marketing definitions in Control Panel and that is a root cause of your trouble.

What you can try to do:

1)

Verify or try to redeploy marketing definitions from Control Panel:

[image]

[image]

2)

Also try to rebuild marketing definition indexes through Indexing Manager from Control Panel:

[image]

I would contact Sitecore Support if the issue still persists.

Comment: ok I will try as you said.

Comment: I tried it. I have two languages. Is that creating problem ?